# How to maximize plt.show() using python on mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to maximize pt.show() on Mac. I'm using Python.

`mac OS X ==10.10.3,
python==3.4.2
matplotlib==1.4.3`

I have already tried the following:

```
mng.frame.Maximize(True)

mng.window.showMaximized()

mng.resize(*mng.window.maxsize())

mng.full_screen_toggle()

mng.window.state('zoomed')


from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = misc.lena()
plt.imshow(image)
mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.frame.Maximize(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you tried to change your backend? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39312957/how-can-i-maximize-my-figure-on-matplotlib-python-using-macos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and I simply used a different back-end than MacOSX one.

Try:

```
plt.switch_backend('Qt4Agg')

figM = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figM.window.showMaximized()
```

You can also switch your backend in the default *matplotlibrc* file, but I prefer the above method for a quick workaround, as I use the MacOSX regularly.

Comment: This still doesnt work for me and gives `Segmentation fault ` error.